# Excel copy pasting values between filtered lists

Tags: excel, filter, paste

I am trying to copy the data from the following filtered list: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KC7V.jpg

I want the 4 values from the above picture, to be pasted as is in the first 5 values from the following picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KC7V.jpg

Such that that final result is the following:

```
LEDGER DIVISION
5H
5H
5H
5H
59
23
```

The issue is that when I copy and paste the 4 "5H" values, it is not pasting it in the visible data. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Copy, not the Paste.
The method below will not copy filtered cells and create a single block of contiguous cells to paste.

Instructions:

Highlight the filtered range you want to copy.

Press Ctrl+G. - This will bring up the Go To dialog box.

Click the Special... button.

Choose Visible Cells only.

Click OK. - The visible cells will be selected as a single range. 

Copy that range using your favorite method. (mine is Ctrl+C)

Select the destination and paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going do this multiple times you should consider using Advanced Filter which can send the output of a filter to a separate sheet. Very handy in some circumstances. Good luck!